# How to prove if something is a function?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I know two conditions to prove if something is a function:

1. If $f: A \to B$ then the domain of the function should be A.
2. If ($z,x$) , ($z,y$) $\in f$ then $x = y$.

Now for example I have two functions:

1. $f:Z \to Z$
2. $g: Z \to Z$

And I have to show that the following are also functions:

1. $h: Z \to Z$ defined as $h(x) = f(g(x))$.
2. $h: Z \to Z$ defined as $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$.
3. $h: Z \to Z$ defined as $h(x) = f(x) \times g(x)$.

Now in all these cases to I would have to show that the $Dom(h) = Z$. Now I show this by showing $Dom(h) \subset Z$ and then showing $Z \subset Dom(h)$. Hence through this I am able to show $Dom(h) = Z$.

Now to show this for the three functions:

1 (a). $Dom(h) \subset Z$: $Dom(h) = Dom(f(g(x))) = Dom (g(x)) = Z$ . (As this is an equality can I use this statement instead showing both sides as subsets of each other?)

1 (b). $Z \subset Dom(h)$: (I don't understand how I would show this side.)

2 (a), (b). $Dom(h) = Dom(f(x) + g(x)$ = $Dom(f(x) + Dom(g(x)) = Z + Z = Z$
3 (a), (b). $Dom(h) = Dom(f(x) + g(x)$ = $Dom(f(x) * Dom(g(x)) = Z$ (Can I do this instead of showing them subsets for each side. Plus here is it correct to say $Dom(f(x)*g(x)) = Z.$ What if the domains of the two functions were different?

Now for each function I have to show that each element in the domain only maps to one element in the co-domain. (How would I show this?)

Is this method correct:

1. Let $(z,x), (z,y) \in h$. Then $(z,x), (z,y) \in f(g(x))$ hence $\exists a,b : (z,a), (z,b) \in g$ AND $(a,x), (b,y) \in f$. So as $g$ is a function $a = b$, and then as $f$ is a function $x=y$ hence $h$ is a function.
2. Let $(z,x), (z,y) \in h$. Then $(z,x), (z,y) \in f(x) + g(x)$ hence $\exists a,b,c,d : (z,a), (z,b) \in g$ AND $(z,c), (z,d) \in f$. ($x=a+c$, $y=b+d$). So as $g$ is a function $a = b$, and then as $f$ is a function $c=d$ hence $x=y$ so $h$ is a function.
3. Let $(z,x), (z,y) \in h$. Then $(z,x), (z,y) \in f(x) \times g(x)$ hence $\exists a,b,c,d : (z,a), (z,b) \in g$ AND $(z,c), (z,d) \in f$. ($x=a*c$, $y=b*d$). So as $g$ is a function $a = b$, and then as $f$ is a function $c=d$ hence $x=y$ so $h$ is a function.

Comment: O_o well, how is your $f\circ g$ defined? Functions should already come with a domain and a codomain, so if the composition $f\circ g$ is defined, it's already from $Z$ to $Z$, so what are you trying to prove??

Comment: I got this question from a quiz of mine. I wasn't able to solve it there so I asked it here. Well I think what it actually means is if the composition is a function if f and g are function. For example f may be from A -> B and g is from C -> D and if the Range of g is not a subset of Domain of f the composition won't be a function. So essentially we have to prove that yes the composition is a function and it is from a specific domain to a specific co-domain.

Comment: AFAIK function is a triplet of sets $(f, A, B)$, usually denoted as $f:A\to B$, such that $f\subseteq A\times B$ satisfying $\forall a\in A\,\exists b\in B,\,(a,b)\in f$ and $\forall a\in A\,\forall b_1\in B\,\forall b_2\in B,\,(a,b_1)\in f\land (a,b_2)\in f\implies b_1=b_2$. A composition can only be defined for $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ and is defined as a triplet $(g\circ f, A, C)$, i.e. $g\circ f:A\to C$, where $g\circ f=\{(a,c)\in A\times C\mid \exists b\in B, (a,b)\in f\land (b,c)\in g\}$. It's not hard to prove this is a function, maybe that's what you want?

Comment: When people speak of a composition of $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$, where $f(A)\subseteq C$, they actually mean the composition of $f':A\to C$ and $g:C\to D$, where $f'=f$ (as sets), it's easy to prove that changing the codomain in this way doesn't break the functionality because the second condition can be restricted to the range of $f$.

Answer (score 2):

I would understand the statement "$Z$ is the domain of $f$" to mean
that $\forall (a,b)\in f: a \in Z$
and $\forall a \in Z: \exists b: (a,b) \in f$.
The first of those two conditions says that 
$\mathrm{dom}(f) \subseteq Z$,
and the second condition says that $Z \subseteq \mathrm{dom}(f)$.

The notation $f\colon Z \to Z$ just means that $\mathrm{dom}(f) = Z$
(because there is a $Z$ on the left of the arrow)
and that the range of $f$ is a subset of $Z$
(because there is a $Z$ on the right of the arrow).
In other words, in addition to the fact that $\mathrm{dom}(f) = Z$,
the statement that $f\colon Z \to Z$ also implies
$\forall (a,b)\in f: b \in Z$.
(There is no implied statement of the form $\forall b\in Z: P$ because the range is
not necessarily equal to $Z$.)

With this interpretation of $f\colon Z \to Z$ and the kind of careful
reasoning you followed in your proofs that $h$ maps each element of its domain
to only one element of its range (those proofs look fine to me, by the way),
you can show that $\mathrm{dom}(h) = Z$ in each of your three subproblems.